# How can I open a link from Chrome, not the default browser, in vscode?

Tags: python, google-chrome, terminal, safari

I typically have Safari set as my default browser.
However, when I click a link in the terminal, it opens in Safari.
I would like links from the terminal to open in Chrome when I'm using VScode.
I don't wanna change my default browser Safari.

I installed 'Open in Browser,' but as far as I know, it's for HTML.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please sanitize your tags: I don't see how your question is related to Python. Also, you asked something about a terminal configuration, but don't mention what Terminal you are running.